# Why is a semigroup $H$ of prime size with proper subgroup $G$ not group?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I know that this is addressed in a corollary of Langrange's theorem, which states that if a group $H$ has a prime order, there exists no nontrivial subgroups, since the cosets of any subgroup must partition $H$ and the cosets are the same size. But which group property is violated in $H$ if there *does* exist a proper subgroup $G$?

For example, if the group $G=(\{1,3,5,7\},·)$ where · is multiplication mod 8, the semigroup $H=G\cup \{2,4,6\}$ is not a group because it isn't closed ($2·4\notin H$). Is it closure which is always violated, or does it differ from case to case?

Comment: For finite groups, being closed under multiplication (and non-empty) is enough to be a subgroup. So yes, this will always be the thing that fails.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I don't think that's what he is saying. It's weirdly phrased, however. $G$ is a subgroup of a semigroup $H$, not the other way around, as is usual for the letters $H,G$ when talking about groups.

Comment: It's particularly odd because the example $H$ given is not a semigroup.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ahh, I read it wrong. But the $H$ here is not a semigroup.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit of a mess, so far.

Comment: Oh, my bad! What is a more accurate term for $H$? I'm just trying to describe a set and binary operation pair which is not necessarily a group.

Answer (score 0):

$H=(\mathbb Z_3,\times)$ is a semigroup of size $3$. It has a subgroup $G$ of size $2$. Try the argument from groups to see why it fails here.

The argument falls apart because the cosets are not disjoint, because $ab=ac$ does not mean $b=c$. So it is the existence of an inverse, and associativity, that allows us to make cosets partition $H$.